Verify that a substring within a string of HTML sits within specific HTML tags in Go
If you have some stringified version of HTML code, how can you verify that a particular substring sits within specific HTML tags? Say I need to verify that a substring sits in between a <p> tag, <li> tag, or <h2> tag. For example:
stringifiedHTML = `<h2>Here is John Doe</h2>
<div>Hi my name is Jane Bob.</div>
<p>Joe Smith is my name.</p>
<button>Jen Willis</button>`

func betweenValidTags(input string, subStr string) bool {
  // code to determine if valid
}

fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "John Doe")) // true
fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jane Bob")) // false
fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Joe Smith")) // true
fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jen Willis")) // false

Edit:
I was able to modify PassKit's suggested code to get it working as such:
var tagRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`<(p|li|h2)[^>]*>(.*?)<(/p|/li|/h2)>`)

func betweenValidTags(input string, subStr string) bool {
    matches := tagRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch(input, -1)

    // Iterate through all matches and check if subStr is within the matched content
    for _, match := range matches {
        // match2 is the match group the contains the text between the opening and closing tag
        if len(match) > 2 && strings.Contains(match[2], subStr) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

var stringifiedHTML = `<h2>Here is John Doe</h2>
<div>Hi my name is Jane Bob.</div>
<p>Joe Smith is my name.</p>
<button>Jen Willis</button>`

func main() {
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "John Doe"))   // true
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jane Bob"))   // false
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Joe Smith"))  // true
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jen Willis")) // false
}


You can use a regular expression to accomplish this.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    stringifiedHTML := `<h2>Here is John Doe</h2>
<div>Hi my name is Jane Bob.</div>
<p>Joe Smith is my name.</p>
<button>Jen Willis</button>`

    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "John Doe"))   // true
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jane Bob"))   // false
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Joe Smith"))  // true
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jen Willis")) // false
}

func betweenValidTags(input string, subStr string) bool {
    // regex for tags <p>, <li>, <h2>
    inTags := fmt.Sprintf(`<(p|li|h2)[^>]*>.*?%s.*?</(p|li|h2)>`, regexp.QuoteMeta(subStr))
    re := regexp.MustCompile(inTags)
    return re.MatchString(input)
}

Playground
This is quite simple to understand but compiling a regex on the fly is expensive.
If you are using this function heavily, an alternative would be to create a reusable regex and manually check for matches.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    stringifiedHTML := `<h2>Here is John Doe</h2>
<div>Hi my name is Jane Bob.</div>
<p>Joe Smith is my name.</p>
<button>Jen Willis</button>`

    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "John Doe"))   // true
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jane Bob"))   // false
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Joe Smith"))  // true
    fmt.Println(betweenValidTags(stringifiedHTML, "Jen Willis")) // false
}

var tagRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`<(p|li|h2)[^>]*>(.*?)</(p|li|h2)>`)

func betweenValidTags(input string, subStr string) bool {
    matches := tagRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch(input, -1)
    // Iterate through all matches and check if subStr is within the matched content
    for _, match := range matches {
        if len(match) > 2 && strings.Contains(match[2], subStr) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

Playground

For completeness can you please add the regexp import. I'm assuming you are not using stdlib, as that would panic at regexp.MustCompile due to the use of back references.

I tried both examples in go playground and neither worked. It appears you can't reference previous capture groups when working with regexes in go. So the \1 causes an error.

My bad, I didn't know that Go doesn't allow reusing capture groups.  Updated answer with imports and playground links.
